# Wordpress pages not loading, after migrating to new host

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, host, migrate

I've migrated my wordpress sites to a new host. Migrated the database correctly, changed .htaccess and wp-config. The homepage of the site loading perfectly fine. But when I click on any of the pages they aren't working.

The directory is

.../public_html/directory_name/site/

and when I click a page it fallsback to

.../public_html/directory_name/index.php.

It happens to all pages including admin/login page.
I've already migrated 4 websites, and this happened on 3 of them.

Tried to look other questions and information, but I'm not able to find what couses this problem.

What could be the reason behind it? I can provide any source code / information if needed.

UPDATE:

So I've managed to fix the problem!

- Turned off all security plugins, before migrating the site (wordfence/ithemes security).
- Deleted .htaccess, and made a fresh one.
- Migrated the site, and changed .htaccess.
- Installed the security plugins

Comment: Update/save your permalinks to see if that fixes it...

Comment: Is the domain same as before? and can you post the .htaccess file? the server can run .htacess files?

Comment: On one of the sites I can acces the admin page with url/wp-login.php. I've tried changing the permalinks, and it couses the pages to load. But when I swich back to the original permalink format it's still failing. The domain is not the same as before. And yes the server can run htaccess files. Also im doing an update with htaccess code.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is too long probably, and code-formatting is not working completely. This is becouse of security plugins. Do you have any alternatives to share it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you facing http://yoursite but http://yoursite/anything

I had a similar problem and it got resolved when I follow these steps.

Step 1: change modification in `000-default.conf` file, file path `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Add these lines

```
 <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

         <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

for more see See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Step 2: It seems mod_rewrite is not enabled in your server. Enable the module with the `a2enmod` command (which creates a symbolic link `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load` pointing to `../mods-available/rewrite.load`), then restart the server:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To list all enabled modules you can use the a2query command with the `-m` flag:

```
a2query -m
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the domain you should follow these steps:

1.Go to the database, for example, PHPMyAdmin and replace everything with your last domain with the new domain.

2.In the `.htacceess` file and change if there is the old domain.

3.If any plugin does not let you login change the folder name in the file manager.

Comment: Ty for your answer! As I mentioned, I changed everything in htaccess , wp migrate db changed all the urls in the database. Also I've tried changing plugin folder name, it does not help unfortunately

Comment: Found the solution! Ty for your help, I've updated my answer. Still dont know what exactly was the reason.

Comment: @AndrásTóth I think it was the `.htaccess` that by removing and regenerating fixed the problem. if my answer helped please like.